# Predefined variables stored in database that variables can be accessed, changed, and shared

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I want to make an Android Game App that loads a "game slot" that connects to a data base with predefined data that will be accessed and changed throughout the activities. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many items, you can use [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), and insert default values in its `onCreate` method.

If there are only few, you might want to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: but can I take the values and have them view in a status window then say I have a shop activity that adds to a value and have it update?

Comment: Yes, you can. I'm not going to post the full code here, but you can take a look at my project here: https://github.com/BinyaminSharet/Icelandic-Memory-Game/tree/master/src/com/icmem . Take a look at DataHadler to see the implementation, and BoardActivity to see how I use it (you may need to browse the code a bit)